# How to Prevent id duplication of dynamic div

Tags: html, jquery, duplicates

I am trying to create divs dynamically my method is working but I am having issue in id duplication. In this scenario I am restricted to creating only 4 extra divs. Below is my code.

Html code where divs are to be appeneded:

```
<div id="bedTypeContainer" class="w-100">
                
</div>
```

Html button code to add divs:

```
<button id="bedTypeAdder" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Add more</button>
```

Jquery code for dynamic div creation:

```
 //bed type adder
         var bedTypeCounter=0;// too keep track on the number of divs created
         $("#bedTypeAdder").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            bedTypeCounter++;
            if(bedTypeCounter<5)
            {
                $('#bedTypeContainer').append('<div id="btDynamicRow'+bedTypeCounter+'" class="row mb-3"> \
                    <div class="col-4"> \
                        <select id="" class="form-select" id="validationCustom13" required> \
                            <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option> \
                            <option>...</option> \
                        </select> \
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a valid Option.</div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="col-2"> \
                        <input id="" type="number" step="1" min="1" max="30" class="form-control max-limiter" id="validationCustom15" required> \
                        <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="col">   \
                        <button id="btDynamicRowRemover'+bedTypeCounter+'" class="btn btn-outline-danger btDynamicRowRemoverClass">Remove</button>    \
                    </div>  \
                </div>');
            }
            if(bedTypeCounter == 5)
            {
                alert("Max number of beds Reached but dont worry you can add extra beds");
                $('#bedTypeAdder').hide();
            }
        });
```

Jquery Code to remove div:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.btDynamicRowRemoverClass', function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
            var idSelector = $(this).attr("id");
            if(idSelector == 'btDynamicRowRemover2'){
                $('#btDynamicRow2').remove();
                $('#bedTypeAdder').show();
                bedTypeCounter--;
            }
           
         });
```

The issue I am facing here is like if I remove an id in this scenario the second row and add another div the id gets duplicated and I need the counter so I do not create more than 4 divs.

Comment: Don't use IDs use class

Comment: can't I need id because later values from these dynamic divs will be sent into the database

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life easier by not using IDs. There's no need. Just use jQuery's `$(selector).length` to get the number. I also made your block of code actual HTML that sits on the page and gets cloned. Alot easier to manage rather than escaping line breaks with an inline script. Finally, to remove, just use `$(this).closest(selector).remove()`

You mention in a comment that you need ids to send values to the database. If you like, show how you're doing that and I can suggest an alternative. There's really no need for the IDs - they will just trip over each other.

```js
//bed type adder
var bedTypeCounter = 0; // too keep track on the number of divs created
$("#bedTypeAdder").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  bedTypeCounter = $('.bed-thing').length;
  if (bedTypeCounter < 5) {
    let clone = $('#template').clone().addClass('bed-thing').removeAttr('id')
    $('#bedTypeContainer').append(clone);
  }
  if (bedTypeCounter == 5) {
    alert("Max number of beds Reached but dont worry you can add extra beds");
    $('#bedTypeAdder').hide();
  }
});


$(document).on('click', '.btDynamicRowRemoverClass', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.bed-thing').remove();
});
```

```css
.bed-thing {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bedTypeContainer" class="w-100">

</div>


Html button code to add divs:

<button id="bedTypeAdder" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Add more</button>

<div id="template" class=" row mb-3">
  <div class="col-4">
    <select id="" class="form-select" id="validationCustom13" required>
      <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
      <option>...</option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select a valid Option.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <input id="" type="number" step="1" min="1" max="30" class="form-control max-limiter" id="validationCustom15" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button id="btDynamicRowRemover' + bedTypeCounter + '" class="btn btn-outline-danger btDynamicRowRemoverClass">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but I need unique ID to enter values later in the database. I have not reached that part of the code since I am still designing the form. Is there any condition i can use to make sure that the id's dont duplicate

Comment: You mean like if you come to the page and it loads 3 beds from the database, and those must keep their ids? In that case, you can use `<div data-id="ID_FROM_DATABASE" class='bed-thing row ...` and when you save, use `$(selector).data('id')` to grab it from the element.

Comment: that would work on editing/updating record right now I'm on user entering the data so I cant pull id from the database

Comment: Right, so in your code when you submit the bed data, if there isn't a `data-id` attribute, it's a new bed and your database should auto-insert an ID.

Comment: yes the primary key is auto incremented but right now the issue I am facing is of keeping the id unique and with a limit of only 4 dynamic divs that can be append and remove based on id. I think I might need to use an array to store id. Like to modify to condition to see which array id isnt appeneded and append that if a div with the array id is removed

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but I don't yet see why you need to hard code ID's on newly created items. IDs should only correspond to database IDs - but again, maybe Im not understanding

Comment: Yeah I'm bound to make it this way. Hey can I set id upon form submission?

Comment: Hmm. I would send the new items via ajax (that is what you're doing right?) - then have the backend return the IDs after inserting them in the DB. Your ajax success function would grab those and assign them to the elements.

Comment: yes I'm sending them via ajax. I didn't understand your answer: "then have the backend return the IDs after inserting them in the DB." why? I need the elements to have unique ids when I send like why would I return the id if im able to send then my problem is solved if they go into the database. Im trying to assign the id so i can send them in the database. I have another code the id stays unique through increment of last id but i need these id's to be in a range from 1-4

Comment: Ah, because once you submit a new 'bed' you might want to edit it. At that point you'll need the ID from the DB to be associated with the bed so you update rather than create a new one. But maybe that isn't a concern in the way you're setting up your code.

Comment: yeah of course values will be editied later but that part comes after this unique id issue is settled

Answer (score 0):

add another variable like

```
 var bedId = 0 ;
```

and update your code like this

```
  event.preventDefault();
  bedTypeCounter++;
  bedId++;
```

appended html

```
<div id="btDynamicRow'+bedId+'" class="row mb-3">
```

note : dont do

```
$(document).on('click', '.btDynamicRowRemoverClass', function(event){
bedId --
})
```

Comment: this wont work because even if I use another variable or removing and adding div the second variable will get rewritten too . If I don't do the note then how do I remove the div?